# Can't Serialize Dictionary with the XML Serializer

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a problem serializing this class. I made sure all classes component classes are public and also made sure there are non null values in each class variables. Is there a reason why I cant serialize this?

Exceptions:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>   Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 'SomeNameSpace.TmpClass .

Below is the code:

```
public class TmpClass : ICloneable
{
    public List<string> str_pattern { get; set; } 
    public int group { get; set; }
    public double tp { get; set; }
    public double sl { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
    public string open;
    public string close;

    public TmpClass ()
    {
        open= "NA";
        close= "NA";
        direction  = "NA";
    }
    public Dictionary<string, SomeClass> stats = new Dictionary<string, SomeClass>();

    // Serialize Data
    public void Save(string fileName, string location)
    {
        string file = string.Concat(location, fileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TmpClass));
            XML.Serialize(stream, this);
        }
    }

    // Deserialize Data
    public static TmpClass Load(string fileName, string location)
    {
        string file = string.Concat(location, fileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlSerializer XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TmpClass));
            return (TmpClass)XML.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    //
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
String Index: 1
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'StringBui
lder.String'. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member Patter
nBuilder.String.stats of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.S
tring, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e0
89],[StringBuilder.SomeClass, StringBuilder, Version=1.0.0.0, Cultu
re=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], because it implements IDictionary.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetDefaultIndexer(Type type, String mem
berInfo)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetCollectionElementType(Type type, Str
ing memberInfo)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.ImportTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo me
mberInfo, Boolean directReference)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo sourc
e, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetFieldModel(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetFieldModel(MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(Str
uctMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, Recur
sionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(Str
uctModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter
limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
 model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Bool
ean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
 model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Bool
ean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElement(TypeModel mod
el, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultName
space)
   at StringBuilder.String.Save(String fileName, String location) in c:\Users\
Wei\Dropbox\Work\Personal\CS\StringBuilder\Data.cs:line 133
   at StringBuilder.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Wei\Dropbox\Work\Pe
rsonal\CS\StringBuilder\Program.cs:line 48
```

Comment: Have you tried with adding XML attributes?

Comment: Whenever you have a question about an exception, make sure to post the _entire_ exception. In effect, catch the exception and then post the result of `ex.ToString()`. In particular, this exception almost certainly has a set of Inner exceptions telling you _exactly_ what the problem is.

Comment: sorry i am totally new to c#. When i ran the program, a error box popped up and i assume that was all the exception message. Is there a way to show the entire message?

Comment: ok i think i got the exception, i will post it

Comment: Yeah. Put a try/catch block around the code: `try {/* your code here */} catch (Exception ex){string fullException = ex.ToString(); string stopHere = fullException;throw;}`. Stop on the `stopHere` line with the debugger, or else display `fullException`.

Comment: It seems to be that it cant serialize the dictioniary. Why is that?

Comment: This link might help: http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-xml-serialize-or-deserialize-dictionary-in-csharp/

Comment: How can i start using `[DataContract]`, which import should i be using?

Comment: Why can't you serialize a dictionary? Why does it matter why? You just can't do it with the XML Serializer.

Comment: very true, but its just I know how to parse this in python.

Comment: if you got other suggestions on how to serialize it in to other formats and being able to be read by other languages, i am all ears. thanks

Comment: Exactly which XML format are you trying to achieve? Why led you to believe that the XML serializer could be used to achieve that format?

Comment: None in particular, i just need to serialize it. So as long as the solution can serialize it in a format that can be parse by other programming language, im golden.